# How can i display the result twice for the same column for different conditions

Tags: sql-server

I have a table as below

```
Campaign       Status
A             InProgress
B             NotStarted
A             NotStarted             
C             NotStarted
A             NotStarted
B             InProgress
A             NotStarted
C             InProgress
```

I need result like

```
Campaign   InProgress   NotStarted
    A        1           2
    B        1           1
    C        1           1
```

Here i am trying to Count the status on condition and display as Different fields 
Will this be possible?
I am trying with the following query

```
select Campaign, Count(Case when Statusid=1 then StatusId else 0 end) as NotStarted, Count(Case when Statusid=2 then StatusId else 0 end) as InProgress FROM [TLDCRM2].[dbo].[vPipeline]
group by Campaign
```

which is not allowing the different fields in the case statement

Please help to display the above 
thanks in advance

Comment: Try     SUM(CASE WHEN Statusid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0)    Count will count zeros and ones and twos the same.  If you sum it, it should work.  I hope.  Didn't test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple options:

```
select Campaign, 
    Count(Case when Statusid=1 then StatusId else NULL end) as NotStarted, 
    Count(Case when Statusid=2 then StatusId else NULL end) as InProgress 
    FROM [TLDCRM2].[dbo].[vPipeline]
group by Campaign

select Campaign, 
    Sum(Case when Statusid=1 then 1 else 0 end) as NotStarted, 
    Sum(Case when Statusid=2 then 1 else 0 end) as InProgress 
    FROM [TLDCRM2].[dbo].[vPipeline]
    group by Campaign
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this

```
SELECT Campaign, 
       InProgress = SUM(CASE Status WHEN 'InProgress' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       NotStarted = SUM(CASE Status WHEN 'NotStarted' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  FROM YourTable
 GROUP BY Campaign
```

Or you should look into PIVOT.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PIVOT function to achieve this result.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT
[Campaign] AS Campaign, -- grouping column
[Campaign] AS DupCampaign, -- grouping column
[Status] -- spreading column
FROM vPipeline
) AS Data
PIVOT(
COUNT([DupCampaign]) 
FOR [Status] 
IN ([InProgress], [NotStarted]) 
) AS PIV
```

**I made the SQL to create this table and its rows -**

```
USE [Stackoverflow]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[vPipeline](
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [Campaign] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
INSERT [dbo].[vPipeline] ([Id], [Campaign], [Status]) VALUES (1, N'A', N'InProgress')
INSERT [dbo].[vPipeline] ([Id], [Campaign], [Status]) VALUES (2, N'B', N'NotStarted')
INSERT [dbo].[vPipeline] ([Id], [Campaign], [Status]) VALUES (3, N'A', N'NotStarted')
INSERT [dbo].[vPipeline] ([Id], [Campaign], [Status]) VALUES (4, N'C', N'NotStarted')
INSERT [dbo].[vPipeline] ([Id], [Campaign], [Status]) VALUES (5, N'A', N'NotStarted')
INSERT [dbo].[vPipeline] ([Id], [Campaign], [Status]) VALUES (6, N'B', N'InProgress')
INSERT [dbo].[vPipeline] ([Id], [Campaign], [Status]) VALUES (7, N'A', N'NotStarted')
INSERT [dbo].[vPipeline] ([Id], [Campaign], [Status]) VALUES (8, N'C', N'InProgress')
```

Comment: +1 for working out the PIVOT, it always confuses me =)

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntactical errors in the query.

Try this:

```
select
  Campaign, 
  SUM(Case Status when 'InProgress' then 1 else 0 end) as InProgress, 
  SUM(Case Status when 'NotStarted' then 1 else 0 end) as NotStarted
FROM [vPipeline]
group by Campaign;
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8f144/4).